# OpenCV-python ошибка imshow()

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv-faq

я работаю над проектом с использованием opencv-python. Проблема заключается в том, что у меня напрочь отказывается работать `cv2.imshow()`, что, как вы знаете, является очень важной функцией. Я пытался реализовать вывод изображения с помощью других библиотек, таких как `tkinter`, но тщетно. Соответственно, код:https://pastebin.com/N3h7dnx2 Текст ошибки: `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1267: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'`

Уточню, что многие способы, что предлагали при подобных вопросах, я пробовал, они не работали. Я уже тысячу раз делал `pip uninnstall opencv-python`, а потом `pip install opencv-python` Также, это может быть важно, в тексте ошибки указывается путь через диск D, но диск D у меня абсолютно пуст, там нет ни единого файла

Comment: Попробуйте удалить текущий opencv   и поставить пакет opencv-python-headless

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению.

Comment: ret почему не проверяете? Может у вас картинка просто не загрузилась?